# Multi count from multi table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table for example:

Table `users`:

```
|Id |User  |
| 1 |Frank |
| 2 |Tom   |
| 3 |Lisa  |
```

Table `cities`:

```
|Id |City  |
| 1 |Paris |
| 2 |Tokyo |
```

How can I have the count of each table `users` and `cities` in only one SQL query ?

I want to have:
- Number of users: 3
- Number of cities: 2

Thanks.

Comment: What results are you trying to get? Also, please add a tag for the specific RDBMS you're using (mysql, sql-server, Oracle, etc.).

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to use the word `sum`? Did you really mean `count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing what you mean:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) AS user_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cities) AS city_count
```

In general, you can use a subquery any place where an expression is allowed, as long as the subquery returns 1 row with 1 column, by wrapping the subquery in parentheses.